# matlab dll throws exception when used in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dll, matlab

I'm working on a project that requires curve-fitting. To get best results I opted to use MATLAB toolkit. I created a dll of this code and tried to use it in C# .NET framework. The dll works successfully on one system but not on any other system.
I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer fo
r 'curve.cfit' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The
type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception. --
-> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLA
B.NET.Arrays.MWArray' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unab
le to load DLL 'mclmcrrt7_17.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exc
eption from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray.mclmcrInitialize2(Int32 primaryMode)
   at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWArray..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at curve.cfit..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at curve.cfit..ctor()
```

I wanted to know why this is happening and how I can solve this issue? I need to deploy my project on multiple machines. What should I do?

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that the program could not find mclmcrrt7_17.dll. This is part of the MATLAB compiler runtime that you need to deploy on each target machine. It looks like you have not deployed the MATLAB compiler runtime.

The runtime redistributable file is available here: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/compiler/mcr/index.html